# How to add an object.key to an existing array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to add a new object.key to my JSON array.

To do that I have defined a new variable `var result = {"bad":1}` then I'm pushing
the items like this `skippedData.push(item.metadata["pico:record"]["dc:description"],{result});`

As JSON output I'm having:

```
[
  {
    "skippedData": [
      {
        "_": "Lungo le mura, al posto del baluardo nord-est, la cosiddetta Fortezza medicea è un degradato complesso di corpi di fabbrica eretti nella 2ª metà del '500 attorno al trecentesco cassero senese.",
        "$": {
          "xml:lang": "it"
        }
      },
      {
        "result": {
          "bad": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Which is wrong since I'm having a new "result" object instead of a "result" object key.

My expected output should be:

```
[
  {
    "skippedData": [
      {
        "_": "Lungo le mura, al posto del baluardo nord-est, la cosiddetta Fortezza medicea è un degradato complesso di corpi di fabbrica eretti nella 2ª metà del '500 attorno al trecentesco cassero senese.",
        "$": {
          "xml:lang": "it"
        },
        "result": {
          "bad": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`skippedData` is an array. 
You are using [push method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) which is adding elements to array.

As I understood u want to add data from two sources in one object, so u can use this way to build new object there with [spread](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread):

```
skippedData.push({ 
  ...item.metadata["pico:record"]["dc:description"],
  ...{result}
});
```

or equal with [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
skippedData.push(Object.assign(
  {},
  item.metadata["pico:record"]["dc:description"],
  {result}
));
```

If u want exactly to modify object already existing in array, u can refer to it by key, e.g.

```
skippedData[0].result = result
```